# How to disable Chrome background processes and updates?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, localization, automatic-update

Some time ago I installed Chrome (as I need to test my websites in it), but it launched uncontrollable background processes and updates, so I uninstalled it completely... Now I decided to install it again. This piece of software tries be idiot-friendly and is completely uncontrollable:

1. **Impossible to install English version**, if your Windows are not English! I switched the language on [the download website](https://www.google.com/chrome?hl=en), I tried search the webpage for custom download, I tried to switch the language in the app also... no way. User is idiot, Chrome is clever again - it knows much better what language user wants.
2. **Impossible to switch off automatic updates**! There's no setting in the Chrome setup. I found some [hack way to do it using registers](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates) but it doesn't work any more. I only found `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Update\` but the setting seems to have dissapeared.

Any solutions for these problems?

The only positive thing I found is that **it still allows to disable the background processes** it runs by default after you close the Chrome. (Just wonder when this setting will disappear, considering the ongoing virus-like policy trend in current software, with Chrome walking in the front...)

Comment: ... it's pain to deal with software that thinks it is more clever than you...

Comment: First of all, why would you want to disable the updates? Second, have you tried this with Chromium?

Comment: @MichaelK, because automatic updates are endlessly annoying. E.g. if you travel and are offline for 2 weeks. Then you finally find some WiFi and need to do something fast, **all** these viruses immediatelly jump on your tiny WiFi connection like ravenous monsters and throttle it to death.

Comment: @MichaelK, no, I haven't tried with Chromium, with Chrome only. But the title states ["Turning Off Auto Updates in Google Chrome"](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates)

Comment: Chrome is known to do this (just install Wireshark and watch how often it "phones home" to Google), which is exactly why I refuse to install it.  As @MichaelK said, try Chromium, or **install Chrome in a VM.  Problem solved.**

Comment: @Breakthrough, really?? I knew it's bad but this is.... awkward!! A real virus. Are you sure Chromium is better?

Comment: In windows you can block Chrome automatic update using msconfig.

Comment: To get this word out of here, this behavior is NOT a virus. So please stop using this word until you know what it means. Have a look here -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus for further explanations.

Comment: By the way, yes, google chrome often contacts google and sends anonymous statistical data and fetches updates if available. Big updates (like the ones that 'block' you connection) are uncommon and only occur if a new major version is released. You can stop chrome from transmitting statistical data in the options.

Comment: @MichaelK, many current programs fulfil the virus definition in many ways: they are often memory resident, doing a lot of unsolicited background actions, unstoppable, and uncontrollable by user. Don't you feel the trend in last 15 years in loosing user's control over what software does?

Comment: @Tomas I noticed this behavior for sure, but there is a clear definition for the word virus and people keep to use it in the wrong way, just like the word hacker is used wrong for so many years now... I do support having the user in control as much as possible, but I also support the correct usage of words like virus. Btw, sending statistical data without any personal information what soever to improve the user experience in further releases and automatically updating software to make it better and more secure is not a virus like behavior.

Comment: Re: automatic updates; ha! Good luck with that. [This poor guy](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=165975) went nuts just asking that it not automatically update in the **About page** and they told him to get lost. Good luck trying to get them to stop automatically updating altogether. `:-|`

Comment: @Synetech, thanks for info, as we can see, Chrome is really a brutal virus... (i.e., uncontrollable program with its own will...). Damn it.

Comment: Actually Chrome is (potentially) pretty good, it is the devs that are the virus. ☹

Answer (score 0):

Chrome will use English as default language. You can change it after you download it. Go to `Settings > Under The Hood > Languages and spell-checker settings > Add the language > Highlight it > from right sidebar, select "Display Google Chrome in this language".` [Source](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95416).

Disabling auto update in windows -
Set the value of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update\AutoUpdateCheckPeriodMinutes` to the `REG_DWORD` value of `0`. If the key doesn't exist, create it. [Source](http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/turning-off-auto-updates).

Comment: Bibhas - as for the language - English is not default - only if you have English Windows. The default is the language of your Windows! **What you write about Settings doesn't work, I tried it already - added English, but it doesn't allow to Display Chrome in it**.

Comment: As for the auto update: are you sure it will work even if the key doesn't exist? What if they changed it? `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google` doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Well, then it's a bug or Chrome doesn't support showing their browsing in that language yet. Report it.

Comment: Bibhas, are you sure you want to say that Chrome doesn't support English???

Comment: Those are official sources, so I trusted them to work. I wish I could try and tell you. But I don't use Windows and it seems Chrome takes the system language in Linux. No way to explicitly specify language. This is how they built it.

Comment: @Tomas I specified an `or` clause. That'd mean it's a bug. report it.

Comment: @Tomas You can also disable Google update by deleting `GoogleUpdater.exe`, delete it from `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Google\Update` (delete whole directory), but be aware that when you install a new Google product the `googleupdater.exe` will be re-placed.

Comment: Yup. that works.

Comment: @Santhos, good, I think I did this some time before and it worked somehow... thanks. But this is really hacky way :-)

Comment: Deleting an .exe to stop it from running and changing a registry entry (clearly mentioned by the programs support) is not '[hacky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hack_(computer_security))'. Also programs you've explicitly installed are not '[viruses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus)'.

Comment: @HaydnWVN, they are not always installed explicitly (Chrome is bundled with many other software..) anyway, many current programs fulfil the virus definition in many ways: they are often memory resident, doing a lot of unsolicited background actions, unstoppable, and uncontrollable by user. Don't you feel the trend in last 15 years in loosing user control over what software does?

Comment: BTW @HaydnWVN, the word "hacker" doesn't only mean [cracker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_%28computer_security%29), it has [more subtle meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_%28programmer_subculture%29), especially (but not only!) in free software. How else would you explain [Linus Torvalds being called a hacker](http://www.rawhack.com/famous.hackers/linus.torvalds.htm)?

Comment: Common misconceptions about hackers.

Comment: @Tomas i totally agree with you about the trend in 'dumbing down' software, or more the lowering of user interaction and lack of actual participation required for most. The trend for bloatware which 'requires' to check for updates every few days/weeks is intensely fustrating in most semi-technical environments. Then again without others of these 'ghost assistants' (eg Event Viewer/logging) most of us (myself included) wouldn't even dream to call ourselves 'Technical'! ;)

Comment: The problem is that the specified key is for Google Update in general, not specifically Chrome, so even if it did work, it would prevent updates to all Google products (which isn’t a bad thing since the devs seem to refuse to behave like every other good dev in the world).